# How to validate constraints of ManyToOne relations?

Tags: java, crud, playframework-2.0, ebean

I've got two models with `1:n` relation and want to use form validators.

If I choose an option from the select, the correct id of the element is stored on the database.
But if I leave it `-- Choose a game--`, *`NULL`* is stored although the game property is annotated with `@Constraints.Required`.

### Models

```java
@Entity
public class Server extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer serverId;

    @ManyToOne
    @Constraints.Required
    public Game game;

    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Game extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    public Integer gameId;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    public static Map<String,String> options() {
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

        for(Game c: Game.find.orderBy("name").findList()) {
            options.put(c.gameId.toString(), c.name);
        }

        return options;
    }

    ...
}
```

### Controller

```java
public static Result create() {
    return ok(views.html.Server.create.render(form(models.Server.class)))
}
```

### Template

```scala
@helper.select(form("game.gameId"), helper.options(Game.options), '_default -> "-- Choose a game --")
```

---

I've already tried to use a `@Valid` annotation to force `play.data.Form` to validate the `Game`-Model during the binding process, but that only causes a simple evaluation of the constraints on `Game` properties, which are not filled. Although a correct game is choosen from the list, it gives me an error that `name` is empty:

```java
@Entity
public class Server extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    @Constraints.Required
    @Valid
    public Game game;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

...
```

---

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by writing a `validate()` method like this:

```
public boolean validate() {
    return Game.gameId != null
}
```

I also looked into the Spring Binding documentation, because Play2.0 Java uses the Spring Binder. In chapter 17.2.4.11 ([link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-optionstag)) they're giving the default option the value "-". Haven't tested it, but it might be the solution.

Comment: Using a `validate()` method would work if global errors should be created, not if I want field related errors? Are there any other abilities to run custom validation and display errors beside the input elements?

Comment: You can, of course, write your own method(s) and call them from your controller. It is possible to add errors to the Form object, by calling the `reject("key", "error")` method.

Comment: Perfect. This is very helpful and suits my needs.

Comment: Doing explicit validation of separate fields in the controller would couple it to the model. And besides, validating the relation (that is: ensure that game.gameId is a number and referring to an existing Game) should be a quite common task. There should be a more straight-forward way of doing this!